# Lenovo Legion 5 Not loading from disk

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I am running into an issue - I can't seem to install Ubuntu correctly onto my laptop. I've tried automatic partitioning and manual partitioning.

Problem:

- I can load from a live USB stick, (almost) no problem - I do have to use safe graphics though, otherwise it hangs up.
- I can go through the entire installation, even use the live Ubuntu system
- After install, my laptop hangs up on the UEFI "Legion" splash, and does not proceed to the grub bootloader.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to boot by doing the following:

1. recover the OEM image to restore the EFI boot partition
2. shrink the windows partition to make room for linux
3. install linux without a boot manager on a new partition
4. mount the OEM EFI partition and install grub directly on top of the OEM bootloader (without formatting the OEM partition)